# InstallShield-2008 + Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installshield-2008

We are using Install Shield 2008 (I know its pretty old as per Install Shield standards) for creating setup for our applications and it has been working fine till now.

Recently we encountered an issue where on performing a major upgrade it creates multiple instances on Windows 7 64 bit machine only. It works like a charm for Windows XP SP3 machine.

What could the reason? I checked the Product Code and Upgrade Code and it seems correct.